# how to restrict the user to access only my application in the tablet?

Tags: kiosk-mode

We are giving tablets to our customers with our own app installed in it. I only want the customers to work with our app only. I don't want them to watch video in youtube or chat with whatsapp. How do i restrict them to use only my application? Is there any way to monitor?

Comment: This happens to be a question frequently asked on our site. Have you tried our on-site search? See [How do I search?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/searching) for help using it. One more hint: check out our [kiosk-mode tag](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kiosk-mode), which is where most of those questions are.

Answer (score 1):

Since Android 4.2 tablet can have multiple users. At least I have seen this in Nexus 7.

You need to do the following:

1. Protect your default user account on the tablet with a password
2. Create a restricted user account and give the user access to apps that you want them to have

Note: Multi-user is not available on Android phones or with older Android OSes.
You cannot protect your tablet from being factory rest by user and having access to all.

Comment: How to create the restricted user account and give the user access to apps?